# Create PNG with a row of numbers inside boxes with Python

Tags: python, graphics

How could I create, using python, a graphic with a row of numbers inside boxes and arrows crossing from one box to another (as in the image below)? Then I'd like to save it as a PNG file.

[image: example of the graphic]

The reason I'd like to use python is that I have to create this kind of graphics in bulks, varying the numbers inside the boxes.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pygame. If you draw the boxes and text you can do pygame.image.save(Screen,'numbersandarrows.png')